# Is sed allowed to create a file if w command or flag is never executed?

Tags: sed, posix

I just discovered if I execute

```
echo foo|sed 's/x/u/w/tmp/bar'
```

with GNU `sed`, an empty file `/tmp/bar` is created, which was not intended, because the `w` flag doesn't apply. Even worse,

```
echo foo|sed 'd;w/tmp/bar'
```

also creates that empty file! Brrrr.

And indeed, [GNU's `sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) admits:

> The file will be created (or truncated) before the first input line is read

I suppose, it's easier to implement, if you don't have to test each file handle whether it's open, but the POSIX definition of `sed` doesn't say the file could be touched without executing the command. The `--posix` switch of GNU `sed` doesn't help.

Do you know the behaviour of other `sed` implementations in this case?

Or do I misunderstand the standard here?

Comment: According to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html: _Each wfile shall be created before processing begins_. So the GNU implementation is correct.

Comment: Note that POSIXly, you need `w /tmp/bar` instead of `w/tmp/bar`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GNU implementation of `sed` follows the POSIX specification to the letter with regards to the handling of the `w` command and the `w` flag of the `s` command. The following is from [the extended description section of the POSIX specification for the `sed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03):

> Each *wfile* shall be created before processing begins.

A "wfile" is a file written to by the `w` command or the `w` flag of the `s` command.

The BSD implementation of `sed`, found on e.g. FreeBSD, macOS, OpenBSD, and NetBSD, has a non-standard `-a` option that delays the creation or truncation of the "wfile" until it is written to:

> `-a`
> The files listed as parameters for the `w` functions are created (or
> truncated) before any processing begins, by default.  The `-a` option
> causes `sed` to delay opening each file until a command containing the
> related `w` function is applied to a line of input.

Comment: For completeness, note that `awk`'s `print > "file"` doesn't have that "issue", the `file` is open the first time `print` / `printf` redirected to `file` is invoked (since the start or since the last `close("file")`). You'd need a `BEGIN{printf "" > "file"}` to get the same behaviour as in `sed`.

Comment: Thank you, Kusalananda. Indeed I missed that point in the docs. I just wonder why this was defined that way, because this behaviour seems so disturbing and annoying to me. Good to have the `-a` option in BSD's `sed`.

Comment: @Philippos The POSIX standard primarily describes existing behaviour to try to avoid wildly incompatible implementations (rather than describing some "best" behaviour). I'm assuming that, at the time, the behaviour described by the current standard was the most consistently implemented.